# How to make mongodb start when server boots on Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm (still) a novice on Linux, and trying to figure out how to make mongodb start when server boots on Linux?

I'm using Amazon EC2 "default" Linux instance (no Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a startup script into `/etc/init.d` or one of those `rc.x.d` folders (depending on the fact under which circumstances you want to start mongod).

So ideally you put a startup script into etc/init.d/ and symlink it to the appropriate rc.x.d folders. Those rc folders mean the following as of the supplied link at the bottom:

- Runlevel 0 is when you turn your computer off.
- Runlevel 1 is single user mode
- Runlevel 2 is multi user mode w/o NFS
- Runlevel 3 is multi user mode w/NFS
- Runlevel 4 is reserved for different vendors to define
- Runlevel 5 is GUI mode.
- Runlevel 6 is when you reboot your computer.

The startup script itself can be as easy as:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/mongod #if you have mongod copied to some linux well known place you may only use mongod
```

To start a default configured mongod process, but you may want to configure it through additional parameters you can get from [MongoDB - Command Line Parameters](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters).

When you want to start mongodb only when a given user logs in you may want to add the startup script code into your `.bash_profile` of the corresponding user.

More can be found in this thread: [Where do you place shutdown scripts?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/where-do-you-place-shutdown-scripts-221808/)

Comment: What does the thread say? Where exactly should you put them? Please include all necessary info here.